# Kendo UI grid with css reference

Tags: css, kendo-grid

I'm trying to write a code that has to be conform certain rules. Currently i'm working on a part that looks a bit like this:

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css"></head>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">    
       @(Html.Kendo()
         .Grid<ViewModel>()
         .Name("currentGrid")
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%; height: 640px;", @class = "gridMenu" }))
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine as it is, but the fact that I'm defining a new style is bothering me. Is there any way to make this reference a style in a css-file? So instead of

```
.HtmlAttributes(new {style = ...
```

Something like

```
.HtmlAttributes(id = currentGrid
```

Where currentGrid would be the id or class in the css-file.

Any help or questions are more than welcome.

Comment: Is it what you want?`.HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "your-class"})`

Comment: @sandro, yes. This doesn't seem to work though. The link i made is exactly like this, but somehow it isn't accepting the stylesheet it seems. If i take away the style from the HtmlAttributes, the grid simply returns to it's minimum-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You can add css for GridId

```
#currentGrid{
 width: 100%;
 height: 640px;
}
```

**Or**

you can add a class and add styling for the class. Following statement adds a new class for existing grid.

```
.HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "gridmenu"})
```

---

```
.gridmenu{
 width: 100%;
 height: 640px;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `.gridmenu`?

Comment: I'm going to assume that your answer is correct, however i'm not able to make the .gridmenu in my css-file alter the size of the grid. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the problem are you facing? Check the width of parent as well to make sure you get 100%  of it..

Comment: The problem is that using {style = "width: 100%; height: 640px;", @class ="gridMenu"} changes the height of the grid, while using {@class="gridMenu"} does not change the height. Which leaves me to believe the code is not referencing the css-file correctly. Or not using it at all...

Comment: @Bloddyeye It is possibly due to width of parent. Why don't you try `#currentGrid{
 width: 50%;
 height: 640px;
}` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: @SangramNandkhile thanks, that fixed it indeed. Could you explain as to why adding the width while i'm only changing the hight has this result? Or is this just a buggy way the code always works?

Comment: I would also like to apologize as you clearly gave the correct answer, but I was focussing too much on the height to see that.